# Laravel 10 multi tenant app Api integration

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

i'm developing a multi tenant app in laravel 10 with tenancy for laravel and also spatie permission package, first i can create tenants with "superadmin" and when i create a single tenant i also create his domain like domanin1.localhost:8000 and i can login in this domanin with credential created when i create tenant and in his own db this credential are in user table. But i need now to do API for the tenants because every single tenant will be use and app to admin his own tenant, but i can't find solution...

here is usercontroller:

```
    <?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers\App\Api;

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);

            // Autenticazione per il tenant corrente
            if (Auth::tenant()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
                $user = Auth::user();
                return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
            }

            throw ValidationException::withMessages(['email' => 'Invalid credentials']);
        } catch (ValidationException $exception) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['errors' => $exception->errors()], 422));
        }
    }

    public function index(): JsonResponse
    {
        // Recupera utenti solo per il tenant corrente
        $users = User::where('tenant_id', Auth::user()->tenant_id)->with('roles')->get();

        return response()->json(['users' => $users], 200);
    }

    public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,NULL,id,tenant_id,' . Auth::user()->tenant_id,
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        // Imposta l'ID del tenant per il nuovo utente
        $validatedData['tenant_id'] = Auth::user()->tenant_id;

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User created successfully', 'user' => $user], 201);
    }

    public function show(User $user): JsonResponse
    {
        // Verifica se l'utente appartiene al tenant corrente
        if ($user->tenant_id === Auth::user()->tenant_id) {
            return response()->json(['user' => $user->load('roles')], 200);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'User not found'], 404);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user): JsonResponse
    {
        // Verifica se l'utente appartiene al tenant corrente
        if ($user->tenant_id === Auth::user()->tenant_id) {
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $user->id . ',id,tenant_id,' . Auth::user()->tenant_id,
                'password' => ['nullable', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
            ]);

            $user->update($validatedData);

            return response()->json(['message' => 'User updated successfully', 'user' => $user], 200);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'User not found'], 404);
    }

    public function destroy(User $user): JsonResponse
    {
        // Verifica se l'utente appartiene al tenant corrente
        if ($user->tenant_id === Auth::user()->tenant_id) {
            $user->delete();

            return response()->json(['message' => 'User deleted successfully'], 200);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'User not found'], 404);
    }
}
```

and here api.php:

```
<?php




use App\Http\Controllers\App\Api\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware(['tenancy', 'auth:sanctum'])->prefix('api')- 
>group(function () {
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('/users', [UserController::class, 'store']);
Route::put('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 
'destroy']);
});
```

Thanks you so much in advance

Comment: In the current state, the question is very unclear and hard to answer, I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77792735/edit) your question to add more details and phrase it better.